# Python Regex match anything not enclosed in curly braces or enclosed in curly braces and quoted

Tags: python, regex

I am using the python regex library `re`. I have a string and I want to match (in order to replace) the text that satisfies either one of the two following conditions:

1. The text is not enclosed in curly braces (`{` and `}`).
2. The text is enclosed in curly braces and is quoted.

For example, for the string below:

```
match-this  ""  {% not-this "match:this:" %}   "also_this"
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^             ^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The parts specified by the `^` are the ones I want to match.

Probably the regular expression will have 2 groups, one for each condition:

```py
pattern = r'(patter-for-anything-not-enclosed|patter-for-enclosed-and-quoted)'
```

Not really sure how to write any of them. I guess I can use positive look aheads/behinds for the second, but still not quite sure. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pattern with [regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/):

```
\b[\w\s-]+\b(?=[^}]*{)|\b[\w\s-]+\b(?![^{]*})|(?<={|\")[^\"]+\"\K([^\"]+)(?=\")
```

See Regex [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iGXwcv/5)

Code:

```
import regex

pattern = "\b[\w\s-]+\b(?=[^}]*{)|\b[\w\s-]+\b(?![^{]*})|(?<={|\")[^\"]+\"\K([^\"]+)(?=\")"
text = """
match-this  ""  {% not-this "match:this:" %}   "also_this"
"""
print(regex.sub(pattern,  "P", text))
```

Output:

```
P  ""  {% not-this "P" %}   "P"
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for the solution! This seems to be working. I have one last question. When trying to use `re.sub()` with this pattern, it looks like that the text being substituted is not the correct one. That is:

```python
>>> import re
>>> pattern = r'(?:[\w-]+(?=.*{)|[\w-]+(?!.*}))|(?:(?={[^\"]+\"([^\"]+)\"))'
>>> s = 'match-this  ""  {% not-this "match:this:" %}   "also_this"'
>>> re.sub(pat, 'P', s)
'P  ""  P{% not-this "match:this:" %}   "P"'
```

The second 'P' should be where the 'match:this:' string is. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: Check my answer now, hope it helps you.

Comment: This works perfectly, it would be amazing if you could change it so that it matches also spaces, so that whole phrases are matched instead of single words. For example, in the text: `text = "match this"`, the substring `match` and the substring `this` would be in the "same match" (if this makes sense), because right now they are matched separately. Again, thanks a bunch.

Comment: Maybe this? `(\b[\w\s-]+\b(?=.*{)|\b[\w\s-]+\b(?!.*}))|(?<={|\")[^\"]+\"\K([^\"]+)(?=\")`

Comment: Yeap, almost perfect. There are some small issues but I don't want to waste your time, your answer has already helped me a lot. In case you want to fix it, the issue arises in this example: `text = {{ not.this }} {{ also-not-this }}`. The `not` and the `this` get matched even though they shouldn't because they are enclosed in curly braces but not quoted.

Comment: This isn't a wasting of my time, I enjoy it if I can help others. pattern can rewrite like this: `(\b[\w\s-]+\b(?=[^}]*{)|\b[\w\s-]+\b(?![^{]*}))|(?<={|\")[^\"]+\"\K([^\"]+)(?=\")`

Comment: Note: This is not a perfect regex that can meet your requirements because I don't know how your input can be in a different situation, I just wrote this to maybe help you or give you some idea that how to write your pattern.

Comment: The last one is exactly what I needed! Thank you for your time :D